# Chrome Dev Tools "disconnected from page"

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

My normal iteration cycle is I make some changes, rebuild my app, and in chrome (with dev tools open) it somehow recognizes that (might be because nodemon restarts on save) and a blue "reload" appears, I tap it and see the updated app.

However, once in a while I see the following screen.  The only thing I know to do is close dev tools, reload and then open dev tools again which totally kills the iteration cycle.  I don't know what specifically is causing this.  Leading up to asking this question, its occurring on every rebuild, but I'm not aware of anything different in my development.  I've had some success with hard restarting chrome but that hasn't worked this time.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Did you find the root cause/fix to this issue?